# How to update Heroku along with Github after the first time commit and creating Heroku app?

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, deployment, command-line-interface

I have created my `Heroku app` via `github` with first commit by following commands.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "my first commit"
heroku login
heroku create
git push heroku HEAD:master
```

My app got created successfully. But I don't know which commands to use after then - if again i want to deploy it after making some changes in my existing code? What are the exact commands then for `github` and `heroku` both respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-deploy your app with the same commands you have done before.

Commands

```sh
git add .
git commit -m "new commit"
git push heroku master
```

Use `git push` for GitHub